# the code is executed before expected, async/await not working as expected

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```js
export const state = {
  lat: "",
  lng: "",
};

// Setting the map

//gets lat and lng and from the browser.

export const addHandlerSetPosition = async function (handler) {
  await navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
    state.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
    state.lat = pos.coords.latitude;

    handler(state.lng, state.lat);
  });
  console.log(state);
};
```

i want to know why the output of the console.log is the state object before assigning the new values although i used async/await to make sure that the console.log is after changing object values

Comment: Because `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` does not return a promise so your await resolves immediately without waiting for the inner callback.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` doesn't return a `Promise`. It's an old-fashioned callback-based method, so doing `await` does nothing. In order to run `console.log()` after we know the position, you need to put your `console.log()` inside the callback function:

```js
export const addHandlerSetPosition = function (handler) {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
    state.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
    state.lat = pos.coords.latitude;

    handler(state.lng, state.lat);

    console.log(state); // here
  });
};
```

You can, however, make it an async function if you'd like. Here's how you can do it:

```js
function getPosition(options) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      resolve,
      reject,
      options
    );
  });
}

export const addHandlerSetPosition = async function (handler) {
  const pos = await getPosition(); // now await works!

  state.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
  state.lat = pos.coords.latitude;

  handler(state.lng, state.lat);

  console.log(state);
};
```

To sum up, `await` only makes sense if a function or method returns a `Promise`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is a function, that returns void instead of a promise, so your await statement gives no effect. [image]

If you do want to await this code, you can do something like this

```js
const getPosition = new Promise((resolve) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        resolve(position);

    })
});

const state = {
    lat: "",
    lng: "",
};
  
position = await getPosition;
state.lat = position.coords.latitude;
state.lng = position.coords.longitude;
console.log('State is: ', state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because `await` only waits on `Promises` and `getCurrentPosition()` does not return an promise.

Take a look at the interface:

```
interface Geolocation {
    clearWatch(watchId: number): void;
    getCurrentPosition(successCallback: PositionCallback, errorCallback?: PositionErrorCallback | null, options?: PositionOptions): void;
    watchPosition(successCallback: PositionCallback, errorCallback?: PositionErrorCallback | null, options?: PositionOptions): number;
}
```

You see at the very right it says `void` that means `undefined`

However you can promisfy your function like:

```
function getPos(){
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(res, rej)
  })
}

export const addHandlerSetPosition = async function (handler) {
  let pos = await getPos()
    
  state.lng = pos.coords.longitude;
  state.lat = pos.coords.latitude;
  handler(state.lng, state.lat);
  console.log(state);
};
```